# How can I query the same table twice with this code (keeping GROUP_CONCAT)?

Tags: mysql

In the code below, which is doing largely what I want, I am querying an attributes table that is linked to a 'venues' table by a venue_attribute table giving a many-to-many.

I am doing this to improve performance when displaying a large list over individual venue pages, where I use factory to load up venue objects. So far this new call is saving me a lot of time.

Firstly I would like to know why I had to use DISTINCT with GROUP_CONCAT to avoid multiple values being shown per venue under a.name? I don't see where it joins twice?

My second challenge is retrieving a rating value which is held in the attributes table, separately from the GROUP_CONCAT returned value. (I have put the table structure below the query). The rating returns within the GROUP_CONCAT (a.name) value but there is only one per venue and I need to show it in a separate column, such as a.rating, within the select statement. I should perhaps hold the rating value in the venue table, and will, if it is not easily retrievable - but I'm interested to see what MYSQL can do and I'm rather basic in my skill levels.

Thanks for your time.

```
SELECT v.venue_id, v.name, v.suburb, v.venue_email, v.venue_phone, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.name) AS attributes, v.review_count, vi.image_thumb_path
FROM venues AS v
LEFT JOIN venue_attribute AS va ON v.venue_id = va.venue_id
LEFT JOIN attribute AS a ON a.att_id = va.attribute_id
LEFT JOIN venue_review AS vr ON vr.venue_id = v.venue_id
LEFT JOIN venue_image AS vi ON vi.venue_id = v.venue_id
WHERE v.status = 1
GROUP BY v.name;

Table attribute
===============
att_id, type, name, abbreviation, synonyms, description, scope
---------------
att_id           int(11) PK
type             enum('transport','purpose','parking','site_control','authorisations','permissions','facilities','rating')
name             varchar(255)
abbreviation     varchar(32)
synonyms         varchar(255)
description      mediumtext
scope            enum('global')
```

Comment: If there's only one attribute.rating value for a venue, but there is a one-to-many relationship between venues and attribute, which row is the rating in? All of them?

Comment: @Ami, I think this subset of my question answers your question? "I am querying an attributes table that is linked to a 'venues' table by a venue_attribute table giving a many-to-many"

Answer (score 1):

For your second challenge, I think the solution is to make 2 joins to the `attribute` table, like the one given below:

```
SELECT v.venue_id, v.name, v.suburb, v.venue_email, v.venue_phone, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.name) AS attributes, v.review_count, vi.image_thumb_path, a1.name as rating
FROM venues AS v
LEFT JOIN venue_attribute AS va ON v.venue_id = va.venue_id
LEFT JOIN attribute AS a ON a.att_id = va.attribute_id
LEFT JOIN attribute AS a1 ON a1.att_id = va.attribute_id AND a1.type = 'rating'
LEFT JOIN venue_review AS vr ON vr.venue_id = v.venue_id
LEFT JOIN venue_image AS vi ON vi.venue_id = v.venue_id
WHERE v.status = 1
GROUP BY v.name;
```

The above query should give you the rating in the separate column in the resultset.

Now for your first question, you do not have to use DISTINCT with GROUP_CONCAT unless there could be multiple attributes with the same name for the same venue. If for a given venue, it is never possible that there can be 2 or more attributes with the same name, you can safely avoid DISTINCT.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your help. I have marked you up as this is helpful to me, I didn't know I could add "where" like conditionals to a join in this fashion - However, the column a1.name AS rating is returning NULL values for all calls. This snippet from mysql probably explains why "If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for the right table.", but there are values and I can prove it by using "AND a1.type = 'rating'" in the WHERE part of the the query - that obviously restricts the query though.

Comment: If there are rows in attribute where type = "rating", it should have been reflected in the resultset. By the way, you are right with your understanding on LEFT JOIN. There is a where condition `v.status = 1`; so perhaps there is no "rating" attribute for none of the venues for which status is 1. Can you please verify?